# не меняется расположение блок в grid разметке

Tags: html, css

Начал изучать разметку grid для адаптивности страницы. Создал меню, которое на полной ширине выглядит по одному, но если уменьшить размер браузера до 600 px, то нужное расположение блоков указанное в коде не применяется. Есть ли добрые люди, которые помогут понять, что я сделал не так. В интернете данную информацию находил, по ней и делал, но по факту так и не получилось. Как видите меню сверху, но потом оно переезжает вниз, и положение блоков слегка меняется, что-то перемещается, а что-то и вовсе убирается (Логотип).
И второй вопрос, как сделать, чтобы это меню сверху вниз перемещалось плавно.?

HTML

```
    <div class="main">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="menuleft">
        <span class="touchhome"><img src="img/ico/home.png"></span>
        <span class="touchmusic"><img src="img/ico/music.png"></span>
        <span class="touchpeople"><img src="img/ico/people.png"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="photoprofile"><img src="img/photo.png"></div>
    <div class="menuright">
        <span class="touchmessage"><img src="img/ico/message.png"></span>
        <span class="touchnotification"><img src="img/ico/notification-bell.png"></span>
        <span class="touchsearch"><img src="img/ico/search.png"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="settings">
        <span class="touchsearch"><img src="img/ico/setting.png"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .main {
    position: fixed;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'logo menuleft photoprofile menuright settings';
    grid-template-columns: '1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 1fr';
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.466);
    border-radius:10px ;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }



    .logo {
    position: absolute;
    grid-area: logo;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .menuleft {
    position: absolute;
    grid-area: menuleft;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .touchhome {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .touchmusic {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .touchpeople {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .menuright {
    position: absolute;
    grid-area: menuright;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .touchmessage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .touchnotification {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .touchsearch {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .settings {
    position: absolute;
    grid-area: settings;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 10;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .photoprofile {
    position: absolute;
    grid-area: profilephoto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .profilephoto > img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    top: -50%px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    }

    @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'photoprofile menuleft menuright settings';
    grid-template-columns: '1fr 2fr 2fr 1fr';
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10;
    }
    

    .photoprofile {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10;
    }
    }
```

Comment: зачем у блоков absolute? Чего то вы тут наколбасили)) И меню без ссылок, это очень оригинально

Comment: ссылки на данном этапе не важны. без absolute не отображаются блоки

Comment: точнее отображаются, но не правильно

Comment: без абсюлют они отображаются так как вы заложили в гридах. В данном случае абсолют это листик подорожника приложенный к оторванной конечности)) 
Попробуйте без всяких дополнений, вы же гриды используете что бы сделать какое то положение, а абсолют ваши элементы вырывает из потока и ставит по другому.

Comment: то-есть вы предлагаете не использовать абсолют??? и вообще позиционирование?